# C++ using list with count() function

Tags: c++, stl

I have a list `L` which needs to count how many 1s it has in it.

```
list<int> L;

L.push_back(14); L.push_back(5); L.push_back(22);

L.push_back(1); L.push_back(1); L.push_back(-7);
```

the function that i have been given is :

```
assert ( count(...,...,...) == 2);
```

i need to know what would replace the `...`'s.

i have tried `L.begin(), L.end(), 1` to replace the `...`'s but it keeps giving me an error saying that is not allowed. So i need to replace the `...`'s without adding any extra code.

this is the error that i have been getting:

> error C2782:
>   'iterator_traits<_Iter>::difference_type
>   std::count(_InIt,_InIt,const _Ty &)' :
>   template parameter '_InIt' is
>   ambiguous

Here is the exact code & error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int A1[6] = {15,8,10,9,12,13};
    vector<int> V(A1, A1+6);
    list<int> L; 

    L.push_back(14); L.push_back(5); L.push_back(22);
    L.push_back(1); L.push_back(1); L.push_back(-7);

    count(L.begin(), L.end(), 1);

}
```

> error C2782:
>   'iterator_traits<_Iter>::difference_type
>   std::count(_InIt,_InIt,const _Ty &)' :
>   template parameter '_InIt' is
>   ambiguous
>
> c:\program files\microsoft visual
>   studio 9.0\vc\include\algorithm(160) :
>   see declaration of 'std::count' 1>
>   could be 'unsigned int'

Comment: the error is that the parameters are too ambigious

Comment: Can you post the exact error in your question?

Comment: Paste in exact code, not snippets. Also, what compiler, what STL implementation?

Comment: Please put exact code and error

Comment: Assuming you included the correct headers (<list> and <algorithm>) and that you used a using directive to provide access to the std namespace (using namespace std), then your code compiles just fine and is correct. I think we lack some information to help you out, please post a complete code sample that generates the error.

Comment: Above code compiles fine in VS2008 and VC6. I guess the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be `std::count(L.begin(), L.end(), 1)` so if this doesn't work all I can say is make sure you `#include <algorithm>`.

This code compiles for me in VS2008:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> L;

    L.push_back(14); L.push_back(5); L.push_back(22);

    L.push_back(1); L.push_back(1); L.push_back(-7);

    assert( count(L.begin(), L.end(), 1) == 2);
}
```

Comment: I have included the #include<algorithm> but it still doesnt work. the error it shows is that the parameters are too ambigious.

Comment: I dont know what was wrong but yea it seems to compile now. I just created a new project in VS 2008 & it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put using namespace std; after all the includes and make sure you include algorithm also and 
then L.begin() and L.end() should work without any problem

Answer (score -1):

Use std::count_if

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/count_if.html

Heres a beter sample:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2d7w2x2%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: i have to use count() because thats whats been given to me. can't add any extra code

Comment: You don't need `count_if` here.